# Are the Netflix Marvel TV series getting blu-ray releases?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil

A few years ago, Marvel and Netflix made a deal where there would be several inter-connected Marvel Cinematic Universe TV shows produced for Netflix.  The first 2 of these, *Daredevil* and *Jessica Jones* have had their first seasons released on Netflix at this point.

However, I haven't seen anything concrete about home video releases (blu-ray and/or DVD), and it's been well over 6 months since the release of *Daredevil*'s first season.  Has Marvel announced plans for releasing these series on blu-ray?

Comment: We discussed this in chat recently. Since Netflix has released some of the  other original shows on disc (OITNB, House of Cards, Hemlock Grove), it's definitely a possibility. Likely just before the release of S2.

Comment: Still no bluray release and season 2 is tomorrow?

Comment: I believe Netflix doesn't actually hold the rights to House of Cards, they just have exclusive streaming rights to the show, and worked in a term in their deal with Media Rights Capital that they couldn't have a physical distrubtor for a significant portion of time (Sony ended up getting physical distribution rights).  Same concept applies to Orange is the New Black.  Disney and Netflix are fairly cozy in business terms at the moment, so its possible Disney simply gave Netflix a blanket contract as sole distributor of their Netflix series, in which case they are likely to be physical media

Answer (score 11):

Netflix typically waits a period of 6-12 months, or more in some cases, to release the DVD/Blu-ray copies of their original series. This is because they want to supplement the demand as long as they can before it becomes reasonable to sell them on other vendors (Amazon) otherwise they would likely see a drop in traffic. You can see with other series such as [Orange Is The New Black](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00TSEVXU0) and [House of Cards](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00IXGTZ8Q) that it isn't unusual for a DVD/Blu-ray release, and so we can expect the same for Daredevil and Jessica Jones.

Answer (score 3):

As of May 2022:

- [Season 1 and Season 2 of *Daredevil* are available on Blu-Ray. Season 3 is not.](https://bamsmackpow.com/2022/02/11/daredevil-season-3-dvd-blu-ray/)
- [Season 1 of *Jessica Jones* is available on Blu-Ray](https://www.blu-ray.com/Jessica-Jones/310594/). Seasons 2 and 3 are not.
- [Season 1 of *Iron Fist*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BKFX59G) is available on Blu-Ray. It appears that [the second season is not](https://www.blu-ray.com/digital/Iron-Fist-Season-2-Digital/31951/)
- [Season 1 of *Luke Cage* is available on Blu-Ray](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0763XHWG2) Season 2 is not.
- [*The Defenders* is not available on Blu-Ray](https://www.blu-ray.com/movies/The-Defenders-Blu-ray/190339/)
- [Both seasons of *The Punisher* are available on Blu-Ray](https://www.blu-ray.com/movies/The-Defenders-Blu-ray/190339/)

Comment: Yet _still_ there’s no Marvel superhero called Blue Ray. Money on the table guys.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly the first season of Daredevil is available to stream on Amazon. So maybe Netflix is going to plan on selling streaming to Amazon before releasing the items on disk.

It is also available to purchase on iTunes.

So I'm guessing that DVD/Blu-Ray will be the last version released since they can get people to buy it on iTunes first.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon offers Season 1 of Daredevil on Blu-Ray for [pre-order](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M1XQ8F1).    Release date is 11/8/16.   This would lead one to believe they are coming out, but at a greater delay than other Netflix properties.

This appears to have been [listed for sale today](http://www.blu-ray.com/news/?id=20005), 10/10/2016.

From the press release:

> Marvel and Walt Disney Home Entertainment have announced the Blu-ray
>   release of Daredevil: The Complete First Season, starring Charlie Cox,
>   Deborah Ann Woll, Elden Henson, Vincent D'Onofrio and Rosario Dawson.
>   The 13-episode first season of the action-packed comicbook drama
>   streets on November 8th.